# How to test building of an aiogram bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

I would like to test my aiogram bot with GitHub Actions. I've set up all the necessary things, such as python, dependencies and so on, but when it comes to the step, where I am actually trying to run my bot, it steps into the infinite loop (which is logical). So, how should I check if it's possible to build my application?

Comment: Depends highly on what do you actually want to test. That it can connect to telegram at all? It's possible to set up a test suite that connects to a telegram test server, but depending on what you actually want to do with your bot, you can probably test a lot of things without connecting anywhere. This of course requires a certain degree of structure and separation in your code.

Comment: Here's an example from my bot on different things you can do: https://github.com/terisikk/janisbot4/actions/runs/4418258464, but the topic is quite opinionated.